# How to paginate a datatable without loading all data in Struts 2

Tags: jquery, jsp, datatable, struts2, pagination

I'm working in some app that uses Struts 2 framework and in the action i load all the data that we need in some `List<Object>` and then in the JSP file this list is iterated and displayed in a datatable using bootstrap framework.

This works fine, but I would know how to do this without load the full data in the resulting HTML, like if i have 1.000.000 (one million) of records.

I don't want that all the records are in the resulting HTML output from the JSP, only the 10 first, and with the pagination load (with jQuery?) the rest of the dataset if is needed.

Comment: from the answer of Nalipu: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side i have to study but this maybe work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is some good aproach, but I i have to convert the `request.getParameter` to Struts variable (declared as privated and then generate getters & setters):

FROM:
https://datatables.net/development/server-side/jsp

EDIT: This link have some `request.gP` with old values from the datatables, instead we have to use the params from:

https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters

Like in an action:

```
private String draw;

private String length;

private String order;

private String search;

private String start;

getters&setters{} //or make it public
```

Then in the `actionMethod` that is called by the ajax make the query to the db and return the dataset.

I will edit this answer when i have the full pagination working with struts2+datatables,

In the datatable there is some configurations that are necesary (see the docs from `datatables.net`):

```xml
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#datatable').dataTable( {
      "iDisplayLength": 5,
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": "paginateTableAction"
    } );
  } );
</script>
```

Comment: this answers is useful is the bussines logic needs to select values from datatables to the action (most common case): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617479/sending-the-selected-rows-from-datatable-to-action-method

Comment: well finally the datatable documentation has the answer :) http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/select_rows.html

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a method in your DAO that have as additional parameters start & end for example :

```
getCustomers( int start,int end){
// get all customers
// sublist the result and get the data from start index to end index
}
```

in your controller you'll do almost the same and you will give `start` and `end` parameters through `POST` or `GET` request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sublistedCustomers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSublistedCustomers(@RequestParam("start") final int start,@RequestParam("end") final int end){
 model.addAttribute("cutomersResult",yourDAO.getCustomers(start,end));
}
```

now you have a part of customers record on your JSP file and it s up to you to decide how to display this sublisted result.

Comment: This code doesn't work with Struts2, and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: the anotations trick can be done with extending the action with the ActionSupport class and with preparedStatement do the querys (all matters who the SwArq say it, so it can be copied from your code, thx and for that i give you a vote up :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to the Enrique San Martín's comment: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side

Any good example should use `iDisplayStart` and `iDisplayLength` parameters, and of course `"bServerSide": true` property of `datatable()`.

Here the link to the blog-post: [Using jQuery Datatable with Struts2 action class using Ajax](http://known-anton.blogspot.com/2012/01/using-jquerydata-table-with-struts2.html).

Comment: its a good start, thx and for that and the help with the edition to my question i vote up your answer, the only problem it that the bootstrap use a new version of datatable (not legacy), so i*Start strings are not longer passed, see my answer for the names of the parameters, but are clearly more understables :), anyway thx for your time to help me to solve this problem :)

Comment: I'm sure you'll be able to adapt the code for the new version.

Comment: yep, its working, filterind and ordering its another subject but is same idea :)